# If a phone number is allowed to start with any digit, including 0, how many 6- digit phone numbers have distinct digits?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If a phone number is allowed to start with any digit, including 0, how many 6- digit phone numbers have distinct digits? have distinct digits, and don’t start with 0.

Answer (score 3):

$10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5$ and $9\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5$

Comment: So, 10⋅9⋅8⋅7⋅6⋅5 is for 6 digit phone numbers with distinct digits and 9⋅9⋅8⋅7⋅6⋅5 is for the distinct digits which doesn't start with 0 right?

Comment: Yes, I think so